# Importing base language updates via Xcode

Tags: xcode, localization, xliff

Importing xliff file with Xcode is really easy but sometimes it happens that the marketing team implements some improvements on the english (base language) strings. Every time that something like this happens I have to perform a diff and manually update the strings in the `Localizable.strings` file and in all the `Storyboards` files. I wonder if is there a simpler way to update base language importing an updated xliff file.

Comment: hello from the future! don't suppose there's a way of doing this in 2021?

Answer (score 2):

I've been wondering the same thing, but haven't been able to find a good answer. However, I figured out the following which seems to work but I'm not certain it is.. **commit before trying!**

You can export the base language for localisation, add new translations to the file (as if you were translating it) AND add the "target-language" attribute with the base language code to all -instances, and finally import the file back into xcode.

Comment: doesn't this process add a new translation to the project?